# Attribute Routing with RoutingParameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I currently have a set of action methods in a web api controller that use Attribute Routing.

```
[RoutePrefix("Paper")]...

[Route("Shape/Octagon/{id:minlength(1)}]
public IEnumerable<sampleShape> PostactionName(string id){..}

[Route("Shape/Hexagon/{id:minlength(1)}]]
public IEnumerable<sampleShape> PostactionName(string id){..}
```

which would work for the following URIs

```
api/Paper/Shape/Octagon/"1,2,3"
api/Paper/Shape/Hexagon/"3,2,1"
```

but becomes unusable once the id parameter becomes to long. Is there anyway to have routing use the parameter id as a form data rather than part of the URI but still keep the Route attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FromBody` attribute to let the engine know that parameter will come from post body

```
[RoutePrefix("Paper")]...

[Route("Shape/Octagon"}]
public IEnumerable<sampleShape> PostactionName([FromBody]string id){..}

[Route("Shape/Hexagon"}]]
public IEnumerable<sampleShape> PostactionName([FromBody]string id){..}
```